# Imagebutton not giving an index off gridview so modal cant open

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi i have a gridview with a button on each row that opens a modal and it works. For testing purposes i gave my imagebutton the same commandName to see if it would also open the modal. Unfortunately it did not...

After a little debugging i found that the imagebutton does not return a index (the row number) so my details modal can not display as i get error:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I was wondering how i can pass the index number of the row using imagebutton.

I have included my code below:

markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UserGridViewControl" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUsers" runat="server" Width="940px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
                                    DataKeyNames="Ref" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewUsers_PageIndexChanging"
                                    AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridViewUsers_Sorting">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ref" SortExpression="Ref" HeaderText="Ref #" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Listed" SortExpression="Listed" HeaderText="Listed" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateListed" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" SortExpression="DateListed" HeaderText="Date Listed" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" SortExpression="Type" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="View Services" HeaderText="Additional Services">
                                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                                        </asp:ButtonField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="London" SortExpression="London" HeaderText="London" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MoveInDate" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" SortExpression="MoveInDate" HeaderText="Movie in Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CommandName="detail"  ButtonType="Button" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton6" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton7" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton9" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>


                                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="Detail" HeaderText="Details">
                                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                                        </asp:ButtonField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
            {
                LoadSortedDB();
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Breaks Here as there is no value in command argument
                Int32 LoweredEmailCheck = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewUsers.DataKeys[index].Value);
                IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                             where i.Field<Int32>("Ref").Equals(LoweredEmailCheck)
                                             select i;
                DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
                DetailsView1.DataSource = detailTable;
                DetailsView1.DataBind();
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("$('#detailModal').modal('show');");
                sb.Append(@"</script>");
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "DetailModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `find` to get object of asp ajax modal popup

**with id:**

```
var modalobj=$find("<%=modalid.ClientID%>");
modalobj.show();
```

**with Behaviourid:**

```
var modalobj=$find("Behaviourid");
modalobj.show();
```

**Working with your code:**

```
sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("$find('detailModal').show();");
sb.Append(@"</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "DetailModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

[Finding modal popup with Behaviourid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2007/02/20/show-and-hide-modalpopupextender-from-javascript.aspx)